# Spring boot HEAD requests are returning 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, cloud-foundry

I have got a spring boot project and I am using Spring security in it. I have got couple of endpoints that is accessed by `HEAD` HTTP method. However, when I access them, I am running into 403 issue. I have tried deployed this app on Cloud foundry.

I enabled the debug logs for spring security and I notice the following on app deployment

```
For security constraints with URL pattern [/*] only the HTTP methods [HEAD OPTIONS] are covered. All other methods are uncovered.
```

Is this the reason for 403 error ?
I have also tried creating a custom filter to return the response as 200 OK and placed the filter with Highest precedence whereas set the Spring Security filter to lowest precedence. Yet the, 403 error.

Spring config -

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("api/v1/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("actuator/**").hasAuthority("Internal")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .bearerTokenResolver(new ...)
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        
    }
```

There is no `web.xml` in the project.

**EDIT**

Adding more information .

1. **HEAD** endpoint details

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v2")
public class GenericController {

    private static final Logger oLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="head", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
    public String getHead() {
        oLogger.debug("HEAD call");
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

2. Adding relevant information about Spring security Config

```
@Profile("cloud")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("actuator/health", "actuator/health/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("api/v2/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("actuator/**").hasAuthority("Internal")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .bearerTokenResolver(new ...(...))
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
}
```

3. I have enabled DEBUG log level throughout the application level. I cross verified with actuator as well and the following is the result.
   [image]

After this, I tried invoking the Endpoint and the only logs I received are as follows -

```
2021-04-22T11: 27: 56.52+0530 [RTR/0
] OUT runtime......com - [
    2021-04-22T05: 57: 56.514492433Z
] "HEAD /api/v2/head HTTP/1.1" 403 0 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.10" "-" "10.0.137.10:61266" x_forwarded_for: "-" x_forwarded_proto: "https" vcap_request_id: "dbe3fb9c-137c-43ac-7e1c-83676999c500" response_time: 0.013301 gorouter_time: 0.000090 app_id: "c40362dd-c3f0-4761-a4c4-4a0e2fd99796" app_index: "0" x_cf_routererror: "-" x_correlationid: "-" tenantid: "-" sap_passport: "-" x_scp_request_id: "bb61bf42-9a83-4b45-b9ae-07ef8db69fe6-60811063-2BE5AA" x_cf_app_instance: "-" x_forwarded_host: "-" x_custom_host: "-" x_b3_traceid: "323746048bfbc90d" x_b3_spanid: "323746048bfbc90d" x_b3_parentspanid: "-" b3: "323746048bfbc90d-323746048bfbc90d"
   2021-04-22T11: 27: 56.52+0530 [RTR/0
] OUT
```

[image: Request]

There is no **web.xml** in the project but on application startup, I received the above warning regarding [HEAD and OPTIONS] request (pasted above).

**EDIT 2**

So, I have re-enabled DEBUG Mode throughout the application and have tried to hit the same API endpoint with `HEAD` and `GET` Http Methods - to show the contrast in logs. Following are the debug logs I obtained by `cf logs <<APP_NAME>>`.

**Note** - Some sensitive URL/User info have been removed from the logs.

1. `GET` call to `/api/v2/head` returns `405 Method Not allowed`, which is expected. FOllowing are the cf logs -

```
 2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.034 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/v2/head'; against '/cloudfoundryapplication/**'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.037  INFO 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] Spring Security Debugger                 :
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ************************************************************
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Request received for GET '/api/v2/head':
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7ac950f3
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT servletPath:/api/v2/head
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT pathInfo:null
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT headers:
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT host: <<APP_URL>>
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT accept: */*
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT authorization: Bearer ....
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT b3: a1a81b1681479e0d-a1a81b1681479e0d
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT cache-control: no-cache
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT postman-token: d1d3f9ed-e3d1-4bb2-86fb-772f4dc2613b
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-b3-spanid: a1a81b1681479e0d
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-b3-traceid: a1a81b1681479e0d
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-cf-applicationid: c40362dd-c3f0-4761-a4c4-4a0e2fd99796
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-cf-instanceid: 067e01f5-c736-4804-7d20-b847
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-cf-instanceindex: 0
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-vcap-request-id: e33cdf0a-9e1a-4d95-7169-6c24a3413357
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-forwarded-proto: https
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-request-start: 1619154128021
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT x-scp-request-id: cab4a4ec-7f3b-47ca-ada6-7236a02aeb16-608254CF-1018CBB
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Security filter chain: [
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   HeaderWriterFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   CsrfFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   LogoutFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   RequestCacheAwareFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   SessionManagementFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   ExceptionTranslationFilter
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   FilterSecurityInterceptor
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ]
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ************************************************************
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.037 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/v2/head'; against '/cloudfoundryapplication/**'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter$DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher@17df04b2
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.04+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /api/v2/head' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.04+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.039 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.04+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.040 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] c.s.c.s.xsuaa.extractor.TokenUtil        : System environment variable I.... is set to null
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.04+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.040 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.04+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.040 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://..../token_keys
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.04+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.041 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.07+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.079 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.07+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.079 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json"
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: ....AuthenticationToken@5b1cc3d9: Principal: user/user@xyz.com; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 169.145.206.236; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ...'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@6e3a74b5
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy@3f28b2df
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/v2/head'; against 'api/v2/**'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/v2/head'; against 'actuator/**'
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/v2/head; Attributes: [authenticated]
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.080 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: ....; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 169.145.206.236; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ...
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.081 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@12459b37, returned: 1
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.081 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.081 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.081 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/v2/head reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.081 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v2/head", parameters={}
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.082  WARN 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.082 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.082 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.082 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.082 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.083 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.083 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.083 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.083 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Fri Apr 23 05:02:08 UTC 2021, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, message=, path=/api/v (truncated)...]
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.084 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2021-04-23 05:02:08.084 DEBUG 7 --- [0.0-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 405
   2021-04-23T10:32:08.08+0530 [RTR/9] OUT <<APP_URL>> - [2021-04-23T05:02:08.021406510Z] "GET /api/v2/head HTTP/1.1" 405 0 136 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.10" "-" "10.0.138.38:61258" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"e33cdf0a-9e1a-4d95-7169-6c24a3413357" response_time:0.064141 gorouter_time:0.000084 app_id:"c40362dd-c3f0-4761-a4c4-4a0e2fd99796" app_index:"0" x_cf_routererror:"-" x_correlationid:"-" tenantid:"-" ...:"-" x_scp_request_id:"cab4a4ec-7f3b-47ca-ada6-7236a02aeb16-608254CF-1018CBB" x_cf_app_instance:"-" x_forwarded_host:"-" x_custom_host:"-" x_b3_traceid:"a1a81b1681479e0d" x_b3_spanid:"a1a81b1681479e0d" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"a1a81b1681479e0d-a1a81b1681479e0d"
```

2. After this, I tried the same API endpoint with `HEAD` Http Method. It return 403, but the spring security logs are missing. Its as if the API is being filtered out even before it hits the `DispatcherServlet` in spring container. The only logs, I received are as follows -

```
    2021-04-23T10: 59: 30.06+0530 [RTR/10
    ] OUT <<APP_URL>> - [
        2021-04-23T05: 29: 30.016853591Z
    ] "HEAD /api/v2/head HTTP/1.1" 403 0 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.10" "-" "10.0.138.38:61258" x_forwarded_for: "-" x_forwarded_proto: "https" vcap_request_id: "f68ece10-c7e5-4d25-46a8-87ab1111448c" response_time: 0.045167 gorouter_time: 0.000078 app_id: "c40362dd-c3f0-4761-a4c4-4a0e2fd99796" app_index: "0" x_cf_routererror: "-" x_correlationid: "-" tenantid: "-" ..: "-" x_scp_request_id: "a729ee4e-7440-4beb-85ac-fdd6bd05e7ba-60825B39-BF580A" x_cf_app_instance: "-" x_forwarded_host: "-" x_custom_host: "-" x_b3_traceid: "c8c055af860ea548" x_b3_spanid: "c8c055af860ea548" x_b3_parentspanid: "-" b3: "c8c055af860ea548-c8c055af860ea548"
   2021-04-23T10: 59: 30.06+0530 [RTR/10
    ] OUT
```

Comment: Can you include a full set of logs with Spring Security set to DEBUG for the request? Start your app, clear the logs, send the request, post everything that shows up. Also, remove your filter. You don't want or need to do that.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I have added the details

Comment: Do you see any debug logs from `org.springframework.security`? You really only need to enable logging DEBUG for that particular package. It will give you sufficient information to debug the issue **if** the 403 is coming from Spring Security. The log you're showing looks like a Gorouter log entry which doesn't come from your app. Try running locally and confirm you get the expected logs. Then try on CF. Make sure that you are logging to STDOUT/STDERR and **NOT** a file. You must do this for CF to make your logs available through `cf logs`.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I am aware of the DEBUG log on the spring-security package, but I did it on ROOT just to capture everything else. Secondly, yes the logs are currently being printed in STDOUT and not in any files. Thirdly, I have updated the post with additional details. I reckon the HEAD call is being filtered out even before it reaches the Servlet container. Could it be due to tomcat on cloud foundry? The details of  JVM used in CF can be found here - https://help.sap.com/viewer/92683dbf07554b01b9d9fd8db39fe622/Cloud/en-US/7f95c9a363b742068c6a77bc6222f84a.html

Comment: I agree, it seems like you're getting spring security logs since you're getting them with the GET request. That piece works, so if the request were making it to your app then the HEAD request should produce similar logs. I suppose the app server could be doing this, but the default Tomcat configuration used with Spring Boot would not, nor would the default Tomcat configured by the Java buildpack. You can certainly customize both though and cause different behaviors. It does seem like the request is making it to your app container though, given that you get a Gorouter log.

Comment: The full output from `cf push` & more details about your app & if you're customizing any Tomcat config (such as adding filters, making application.properties adjustments or making any programmatic changes) would all be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the security filter bypassed or else your app will still try doing authentication on it.

Try adding:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD, "/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
```

before

```
.antMatchers("api/v1/**").authenticated()
```